# Django-admin validation on ManyToMany Field

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models, django-admin

I have a django model where I have a Module class which can have a field 'sort' set to one of 4 values (Video, Article, Quiz, Test).  If Video or Article are selected then I have validation in place to ensure the field 'textfile' (which is an uploaded file) is not null.  I want validation that if Quiz or Test is selected then at least one question is also added.  You can see my attempted validation in the class Module below but it doesn't work.

Here are is models.py:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Question")
    QUESTION_TYPE = (
        ('Multi', 'Multiple Choice (one correct answer)'),
        ('Check', 'Multiple Answers'),
        ('Matched', 'Match Responses on left with answers on right'),
    )
    sort = models.CharField(
        default="Multi",
        max_length=7,
        verbose_name = "Question Type",
        choices = QUESTION_TYPE)
    answer = models.ManyToManyField(
        Answer,
        through         = 'QuestionAnswer',
        related_name    = 'answer',
        verbose_name    = 'Answer',
        help_text       = 'Answers to this Question'
        )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)


class Module(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Module Title', max_length=50)
    MODULE_TYPE = (
        ('Video', 'Video'),
        ('Quiz', 'Quiz'),
        ('Article', 'Article'),
        ('Test','Test')
    )
    sort = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Module Content',
        default="Video",
        max_length=7,
        choices = MODULE_TYPE)
    textfile = models.ForeignKey(DataFile, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Data File' )
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Module Description')    
    weight = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="Module Weighting", help_text="Provide the weight you want this module to carry in the course final score.")
    question = models.ManyToManyField(
        Question,
        through         = 'ModuleQuestions',
        related_name    = 'question',
        verbose_name    = 'Question',
        help_text       = 'Questions in this Module'
        )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)

    def clean (self):
        if self.sort in ['Video','Article']:
            if not self.textfile:
                 raise ValidationError(
                    _("Videos and Articles must have an linked Data File"),
                    )
        if self.sort in ['Quiz','Test']:
            if not self.question :
                raise ValidationError (
                    _("Quiz and Test Modules must have at least 1 Question"),
                )

class ModuleQuestions(models.Model):
    module = models.ForeignKey(
        Module,
        verbose_name    = 'Module',
        help_text       = 'Module is part of a Course.',
    )
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Question,
        verbose_name    = 'Question',
        help_text       = 'Quiz and Test Modules have Questions allocated to them.',
    )       
    order = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name    = 'Order',
        help_text       = 'The order the Questions are presented to the student',
    )
```

And here is my admin.py

```
class ModuleQuestionsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ModuleQuestions
    extra = 1

class ModuleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (ModuleQuestionsInline,)

class QuestionAnswerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = QuestionAnswer
    extra = 1


class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (QuestionAnswerInline,)


admin.site.register(Module, ModuleAdmin)
admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-users/f_MKyPg_C4w/0WMJol1atOoJ

> Basically, you can't. M2m fields are saved after the model is saved,
>   so you either get objects that are not yet ready for that check (as
>   you experienced) or you will test the previous value of the m2m field,
>   neither of which is what you want.
>
> You can modify the admin interface and do the validation in the
>   AdminForm, or perhaps catch the m2m_changed signal and do some checks
>   there, but you can't do the validation you want in the clean method.

Comment: I don't like this answer because it is not what I want but I agree it is right